# OnTouchListener instead setOnTouchListener

Tags: android

I have a Button and I want the user to be able to move it, I tried to use the function I use normally `setOnTouchListener` but this function is no longer exists.
The only similar function exists is the function `OnTouchListener` but I d'ont know how to use it.
How do I use this function? Or do I need to use another function?
I would be grateful if you help me, thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

How is `setOnTouchListener` not applicable ? it is a `View method` and not specific to a type like a `Button`

```
    Button a = null; 
    a.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: There might be some sort of bug. Try to compile it, it should work.